# XNA NAudio WaveChannel32 print line when replay end

Tags: c#, xna, naudio, wave, replay

I'm using NAudio WaveChannel32 to replay recorded sound, now I wish to print some lines automatically when the Replay has finished.

So in the XNA Update function, it's like :

```
if(*Replay has finished*)
// Do Something
else
//Do some other things
```

What is the if condition supposed to be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

NAudio output devices all raise the `PlaybackStopped` event, which is the best way to determine when replay has finished.